# Scheduled cron job not getting executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a cron job scheduled as follows inside an EC2 instance operating on Amazon Linux OS:

```
51 7 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/set_access_token.py > /home/ec2-user/access_token_logs.txt
```

The job is not getting executed despite providing the native path of python3 and specifying the time to run in UTC.

I am not getting any cron logs inside the /var/log folder

Comment: Here's a fairly detailed answer on how to debug cron: https://serverfault.com/a/449652/305746 . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the script using the same command  (`/usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/set_access_token.py`) and check for any errors?
If this script run very well, Update the cron job to send both standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`) to the log file:

```
51 7 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ec2-user/set_access_token.py > /home/ec2-user/access_token_logs.txt 2>&1
```

After making these changes, wait for the cron job to run again at the scheduled time, and then check the contents of `/home/ec2-user/access_token_logs.txt` for any error messages.

Comment: I tried running the script with the same command as mentioned in the crontab. It is running but none of the logs are getting logged in the access_token_logs.txt file.

Comment: Maybe ec2-user directory have no permission to create file.